# Rails app denied access to mysql for user root @ localhost

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm running Linux Ubuntu 18.04.5, mysql server version 5.7.31, and Rails 6.0.3.4

I made my new app with `rails new classic_models -d mysql -T`

This is the `database.yml` file it generated for me:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: classic_models_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: classic_models_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: classic_models_production
  username: classic_models
  password: <%= ENV['CLASSIC_MODELS_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

When I run `bundle exec rails db:create`, `rails db:create` and other `db:` commands, I get this error:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
Couldn't create 'classic_models_development' database. Please check your configuration.
rails aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

I think it's ok that the config file doesn't specify a password for the development database, because when I run `sudo mysql -p` I'm able to access the mysql prompt just by pressing ENTER when it prompts me for a password. And I also ran some other commands to explicitly set the password to an empty string, just to be sure that wasn't the issue.

I tried adding `host: localhost` to the default part of the config file, but that didn't change anything. I also tried adding `host: 127.0.0.1` to the config file instead, but that didn't help either.

When I run `sudo mysqladmin variables | grep socket` the socket string displayed is: `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` which I think means the socket bit of the config file is correct.

When I run `netstat -an | grep 3306` the address `127.0.0.1:3306` appears and so does `LISTEN`, which I think means it's listening on the right port.

The only other possibly relevant thing I can think to mention is that when I run `mysql` or `mysql -p` without `sudo` in front of it, the error I get contains this same string:
`Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

I've been combing through other threads about what sounds like the same issue on here for hours, trying different things, but haven't found a solution. Please don't mark this question as a duplicate and link to any of those other pages.

If anyone could suggest anything else I could try, I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set password for root user in mysql first. For this please follow these steps.

Step 1: Login into MySQL with root user. When mysql will ask for password just press enter.

```
$ sudo mysql -u root -p
```

Step 2: Set password for root user. Please replace `NewPassword` with your desired password. After setting this command please follow step 1 and when system will ask password, please put your new password and press enter.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NewPassword';
```

Step 3: Use this password in your `database.yml` file.

```
# config/database.yml

default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password: NewPassword
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: classic_models_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: classic_models_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: classic_models_production
  username: classic_models
  password: <%= ENV['CLASSIC_MODELS_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

I think this will help you. Thanks :-)

Comment: Hi, this did not work. I followed the steps, but I still get the "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'" error when I try to run "rails db:create".
I made sure to set the password in the file to the same string I entered in the query.
I also made sure to leave the mysql prompt after running your query and log back in using my new password.
I noticed that when I ran your "ALTER USER [...]" query in the mysql prompt, the result was: "Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)".  Does that mean nothing happened?
I'm still able to log into mysql prompt with no password (as well as with new pw).

Comment: Hi you can uninstall mysql and install it again. Then follow the steps.

Comment: I uninstalled mysql, reinstalled it, set a root password during installation, and found that everything was working when the installation was finished and I set the new password in the Rails file. I must have done something wrong during the first mysql installation (or when I subsequently tried to set the password to an empty string in the mysql prompt). Whatever the problem was, it's over now. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I am happy to help you. :)